# recordtype by using utility class

Tags: apex, developer

I need to get recordtype of account so i have written in this way

```
Id AccRecTypeId = Account.sObjectType.getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('Health_Plan').getRecordTypeId();
```

but my lead told to use utility class where there is a method for recordtypes, how would i write that have method in my utility class

```java
  public static Id getRecordTypeId(String objectName, String recordTypeDevName) {
        Map<String, Id> recordTypeIdMap = getRecordTypeIdMap(objectName);

        if (recordTypeIdMap.containsKey(recordTypeDevName))
            return recordTypeIdMap.get(recordTypeDevName);
        else
            return null;
    }
```

how would i call this?

Comment: For the answers that are providing the utility method, I don't think that's what @user75305 is looking for. From what I understand, they already have a utility class (notice that the getRecordTypeId method class another method, getRecordTypeIdMap, that isn't displayed here). The lead is just asking him/her to use this existing utility method, rather than go through the schema manually.

Comment: Why not just ask your lead to explain better?

Answer (score 1):

I think, you didn't really get what your lead wants from you. In my opinion (please, apologize me if I get it wrong), he wants method like this one in UtilityClass:

```
public static Id getRecordTypeId(String objectName, String recordTypeDevName) {
    return Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objectName).getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get(recordTypeDevName).getRecordTypeId();
}
```

And you can call this method from your class as:

```
Id recTypeId = UtilityClass.getRecordTypeId('Account', 'Health_Plan');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure I understand, but if you are just looking to call the utility method, then you will just call the class first. You haven't provided the name of this utility Apex Class, so I will just use an example.

Imagine the class is called Apex_Utils.cls, then when you want to call it, you would use

```java
Id recTypeId = Apex_Utils.getRecordTypeId( 'Account', 'Health_Plan' );
```

The method is taking in strings, so we just pass in the values as strings. This is a hard coded way of calling it.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine a call to a utility method

```
Id rtId = Util.getRecordTypeId(Account.SObjectType, 'Health_Plan');
```

implemented as:

```
public static ID getRecordTypeId(Schema.SobjectType sObjType, String rtName){


     // Try DevName - supported through schema as of V43
    Map<String, Schema.RecordTypeInfo>  rtNameToRtInfoMap = sObjType.getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName();
    if (rtNameToRtInfoMap.containsKey(rtName))
        return rtNameToRtInfoMap.get(rtName).getRecordTypeId();


    // not found, try label
    rtNameToRtInfoMap   = sObjType.getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfosByName();
    if (rtNameToRtInfoMap.containsKey(rtName))
        return rtNameToRtInfoMap.get(rtName).getRecordTypeId();

    throw new InvalidRecordTypeNameException('No such recordType: '+
            rtName +' for SObject: ' + sObjType + ' . N.B. Names are case sensitive');
}
```